# inertial settings not working

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My world file `my_task.world`  is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.4">
<world name="default">
<include>
  <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
</include>
<include>
  <uri>model://sun</uri>
</include>
<model name="my_mesh">
  <pose>0.2 0 0  0 0 0</pose>
  <static>true</static>
  <link name="pad_body">
    <inertial>
      <pose>0.315 0 0.0885 0 0 0</pose>
      <mass>100.0</mass>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>1.0</ixx>
        <ixy>0.0</ixy>
        <ixz>0.0</ixz>
        <iyy>1.0</iyy>
        <iyz>0.0</iyz>
        <izz>1.0</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
            <mesh>
                <uri>model://visual/taskpad.dae</uri>
            </mesh>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual">
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
        <uri>model://visual/taskpad.dae</uri>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
</model>
</world>
</sdf>
```

But the inertial settings not working,  after run the following command,

```
$ gazebo  my_task.world
```

gazebo always show its mass and moment of inertial as gazebo default values.

Any help will be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16328/inertial-settings-not-working/) by [jacknlliu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3320/jacknlliu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What's happening is that you're creating a static model (`<static>true</static>`), which means the model's inertia will be ignored and it won't be affected by physics.

But I can see how displaying the default values can be confusing. I opened an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2286/inertial-properties-for-static-models) about this.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0